# Derivative of $f(X)=X^2$ for $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I am not looking for a solution, since this is a task from my assignment - rather a sanity check, since I spent way too much time thinking about this and I am thinking that there is possibly something wrong.  The task goes like this:

Prove that the function: $D f(X): \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $, $X \rightarrow X^2$ is differentiable and that the Jacobian matrix $Df(X)$ at $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ satisfies:
$$ 
Df(X)(H) = HX + XH \text{   for } H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}
$$
Hint: By definition, $Df(X): \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is given via $(Df(X)(H))_{i, j} = \sum_{k,l=1}^n \partial x_{k, l} f_{i, j}(X)H_{k, l}$ for $i, j \in \{1, ..., n\}$ and $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

Now, here goes my doubt with the statement: How is it possible that the codomain of the derivative $Df(X)$ is $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$? I would expect the Jacobian to be a 4D tensor - for each output in the matrix $X^2$ we are looking at how the slight perturbations in the input cause it to change, yielding a tensor of size $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n \times n \times n}$.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What is the data type of a linear map from $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$ to $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$ if not a "4D tensor"?

Comment: You are right, I totally overlooked that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is mostly right. But there's one crucial distinction: while $Df(X)$ is of rank $4$, $Df(X)(H)$ is of rank $4-2=2$ because $H$ is of rank $2$.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. Can you elaborate a bit about why $Df(X)$ is of rank 4, and $H$ is of rank 2? Do you use the term rank in the traditional sense?

Comment: @ZafirStojanovski I mean tensor rank (which you called dimension) rather than matrix rank, although even the former could be $n\times n\times n\times n$ vs. $n\times n$ instead of $4$ vs $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $f$ at $X$ is not the $n \times n$ matrix $df(X)(H)$. Rather, the derivative is the *linear map* $df(X):\Bbb R^{n \times n} \to \Bbb R^{n \times n}$. If we interpret this object as a tensor array, then it is indeed 4-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has helped a lot